# Amazon Alexa Debugging

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am working on Skill related to [audio with Nodejs](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player), but once I made some changes I found it's difficult to debug here.

I added several `console.log` and also tried by adding `debugger` but I didn't understand where to check those `console.log` ?

- Can anyone tell me an easy way to debugging Alexa skill (I already checked [console.awe.amazon](http://console.aws.amazon.com) but seems unrelated everything)

Comment: Run it locally & debug

Comment: Locally how ? @James

Answer (score 6):

In case of having an Alexa hosted skill. Go to the code section. In your lower left the logs link is shown.

[image: Alexa hosted skill logs]

Only if you hosted your skill using lambda, which therefore means you have an aws account, you have the cloudwatch linking which lambdas have by default.

Comment: Remember to choose the appropriate region in CloudWatch.

Answer (score 3):

An important step in Alexa Skill Development is to examine the logs by enabling the [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) for your skill. It logs out the sequence of events as well as `console.log()` that one has put in the code.

You have to provide CloudWatch access permission for the role that you supplied when setting up the Lambda Function for your Alexa Skill.
[image: Attaching policy]
[image]

Further, if you want to debug the execution locally, you can make use of this extremely useful tool, [Bespoken](https://bespoken.io/)